# Ember project crashes after upgrading Bootstrap from 4.1.2 to 4.1.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, yarnpkg, ember-bootstrap

I have encountered a very strange problem while updating my project dependencies. I had Bootstrap 4.0.0 installed and installing the latest (4.1.3) version makes my project unusable. While rendering the page I get those errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of null
    at Environment.commit (vendor.js:22569)
    at Environment.commit (vendor.js:32631)
    at InteractiveRenderer._renderRootsTransaction (vendor.js:34756)
    at InteractiveRenderer._renderRoot (vendor.js:34686)
    at InteractiveRenderer._appendDefinition (vendor.js:34611)
    at InteractiveRenderer.appendOutletView (vendor.js:34599)
    at invokeWithOnError (vendor.js:24513)
    at Queue.flush (vendor.js:24422)
    at DeferredActionQueues.flush (vendor.js:24575)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of null
    at Class.teardown (vendor.js:110423)
    at Class.willDestroyElement (vendor.js:110416)
    at Class.trigger (vendor.js:60712)
    at Class.superWrapper [as trigger] (vendor.js:58700)
    at ComponentStateBucket.destroy (vendor.js:35913)
    at SimpleBlockTracker.destroy (vendor.js:18333)
    at SimpleBlockTracker.destroy (vendor.js:18333)
    at SimpleBlockTracker.destroy (vendor.js:18333)
    at SimpleBlockTracker.destroy (vendor.js:18333)
    at UpdatableBlockTracker.destroy (vendor.js:18333)
```

I tried to debug it with Ember Inspector. I have [three pending promises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po57N.png) with the same trace:

```
Ember Inspector (Promise Trace): 
    at new Promise (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:66433:28)
    at new Enumerator (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:66009:22)
    at Function.all (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:66173:12)
    at all$1 (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:66950:20)
    at Class.sendPending (<anonymous>:801:22)
    at Class.watch (<anonymous>:861:14)
    at sendEvent (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:37374:18)
    at Class.trigger (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:52321:33)
    at wrap (<anonymous>:3462:14)
```

I consider it weird for a couple of reasons:

1. After downgrading to 4.1.2, everything works fine.
2. 4.1.3 is a bugfix release, [which doesn't change anything important](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/compare/v4.1.2...v4.1.3) in the JS files.
3. After 4.1.2 -> 4.1.3 upgrade, the only difference in `yarn.lock` is a version of `bootstrap` package, so it's not caused by the update of some Bootstrap's dependencies.

What's the reason of this behaviour?

Here's my [package.json dependencies list](https://pastebin.com/s5kXgGdN). Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap 4.1.3 via the `ember-bootstrap` library without issue. I suspect the issue is with the way the bootstrap javascript is imported from the node_modules into your application `via ember-cli-boostrap-4`.

You should probably update your `ember-cli-bootstrap-4` to the latest version (0.6.0) so the addon imports the files correctly against the latest build of bootstrap.